# Divide Oracle CLOB to Multiple JSON with Node JS

Tags: node.js, json, oracle, clob

I am trying to convert a Single Oracle CLOB data into Multiple JSON file with Node js. I have used `oracledb.fetchAsString = [ oracledb.CLOB ];` to fetch Oracle CLOB data. Here is my Node js code -

```
const express = require ('express');
const app = express ();
const port = 8080;
const dbConfig = require ('./db.js');
const oracledb = require ('oracledb');


app.get ('/', (req, res) => {
  var jsonstring;
  oracledb.getConnection (dbConfig, function (err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;
    oracledb.fetchAsString = [ oracledb.CLOB ];
    connection.execute (
      'select topic from table',
      {},
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) { console.error(err.message); return; }
      if (result.rows.length === 0)
        console.error("No results");

      else {
        var clob = result.rows[0][0];
        console.log(clob);

      }
        });
      }
    );
  });

app.listen (port, () => console.log (`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

And Here is my console output -

```
{"Data":[{"Country":"A","OrderNo":"1","Method":" indoor ","WorkOrderNo":"1","Zipcode":"3","OriginalTimeSlot":"2019-12-","CurrentTimeSlot":"2019-12-13","Status":"","WOCreationDate":"2019-11-09","ModifactionDate":"2019-12-11","Dispatch":{"Status":"00","DispatchUnit":[]},"Par":{"Parcel":[{"Active":true,"Weight":284.572,"Volume":0.68,"Trackingstatus":"","Number":"1"},{"Active":true,"Weight":5.396,"Volume":0.01,"Trackingstatus":"","Number":"16"},{"Active":true,"Weight":362.777,"Volume":0.831321,"Trackingstatus":"","Number":"162"}]},"TimeSlotId":"7a2bb6eb-b7a2-4033-8485-0df4015a3938"},{"Country":"B","OrderNo":"162570460","Method":"customer ","WorkOrderNo":"2","Zipcode":"2","OriginalTimeSlot":"2019-11-21","CurrentTimeSlot":"2019-11-21","Status":"90","WOCreationDate":"2019-11-17","ModifactionDate":"2019-12-11","Dispatch":{"Status":"20","DispatchUnit":[{"Unit":"017","Time":"2019-11-20"}]},"Par":{"Parcel":[{"Active":true,"Weight":12.271,"Volume":0.047,"Trackingstatus":"90","Number":"00935297810003971677"},{"Active":true,"Weight":14.668,"Volume":0.038042,"Trackingstatus":"90","Number":"00935297810003971684"}]},"TimeSlotId":"e3fe1936-64f9-42de-b2c4-0ddf00529720"}]}
```

Now I want to create 2 different JSON file from this output like below -

JSONFILE1:

```
{"Country":"A","OrderNo":"1","Method":" indoor ","WorkOrderNo":"1","Zipcode":"3","OriginalTimeSlot":"2019-12-","CurrentTimeSlot":"2019-12-13","Status":"","WOCreationDate":"2019-11-09","ModifactionDate":"2019-12-11","Dispatch":{"Status":"00","DispatchUnit":[]},"Par":{"Parcel":[{"Active":true,"Weight":284.572,"Volume":0.68,"Trackingstatus":"","Number":"1"},{"Active":true,"Weight":5.396,"Volume":0.01,"Trackingstatus":"","Number":"16"},{"Active":true,"Weight":362.777,"Volume":0.831321,"Trackingstatus":"","Number":"162"}]},"TimeSlotId":"7a2bb6eb-b7a2-4033-8485-0df4015a3938"}
```

JSONFILE2:

```
{"Country":"B","OrderNo":"162570460","Method":"customer ","WorkOrderNo":"2","Zipcode":"2","OriginalTimeSlot":"2019-11-21","CurrentTimeSlot":"2019-11-21","Status":"90","WOCreationDate":"2019-11-17","ModifactionDate":"2019-12-11","Dispatch":{"Status":"20","DispatchUnit":[{"Unit":"017","Time":"2019-11-20"}]},"Par":{"Parcel":[{"Active":true,"Weight":12.271,"Volume":0.047,"Trackingstatus":"90","Number":"00935297810003971677"},{"Active":true,"Weight":14.668,"Volume":0.038042,"Trackingstatus":"90","Number":"00935297810003971684"}]},"TimeSlotId":"e3fe1936-64f9-42de-b2c4-0ddf00529720"}
```

How can I divide like this?

Comment: There might a tip or two in [So you want to use JSON in Oracle Database with Node.js?](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/so-you-want-to-use-json-in-oracle-database-with-nodejs)

Comment: @ChristopherJones I am able to connect and fetch data from Oracle. As CLOB data fetching as String, I am not able to divide it.

Comment: I can help with this, but something doesn't seem right. Your console.log is: `console.log(clob);`. Your query is: `select topic from table`. But your console output starts with: `{"Data":`. Where is the `Data` coming from?

Comment: @DanMcGhan its from CLOB data itself.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll post an answer based on your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of the code to deal with the data once you have fetched it is:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// This is the data you said you had fetched
const clob = {"Data":[{"Country":"A","OrderNo":"1","Method":" indoor ","WorkOrderNo":"1","Zipcode":"3","OriginalTimeSlot":"2019-12-","CurrentTimeSlot":"2019-12-13","Status":"","WOCreationDate":"2019-11-09","ModifactionDate":"2019-12-11","Dispatch":{"Status":"00","DispatchUnit":[]},"Par":{"Parcel":[{"Active":true,"Weight":284.572,"Volume":0.68,"Trackingstatus":"","Number":"1"},{"Active":true,"Weight":5.396,"Volume":0.01,"Trackingstatus":"","Number":"16"},{"Active":true,"Weight":362.777,"Volume":0.831321,"Trackingstatus":"","Number":"162"}]},"TimeSlotId":"7a2bb6eb-b7a2-4033-8485-0df4015a3938"},{"Country":"B","OrderNo":"162570460","Method":"customer ","WorkOrderNo":"2","Zipcode":"2","OriginalTimeSlot":"2019-11-21","CurrentTimeSlot":"2019-11-21","Status":"90","WOCreationDate":"2019-11-17","ModifactionDate":"2019-12-11","Dispatch":{"Status":"20","DispatchUnit":[{"Unit":"017","Time":"2019-11-20"}]},"Par":{"Parcel":[{"Active":true,"Weight":12.271,"Volume":0.047,"Trackingstatus":"90","Number":"00935297810003971677"},{"Active":true,"Weight":14.668,"Volume":0.038042,"Trackingstatus":"90","Number":"00935297810003971684"}]},"TimeSlotId":"e3fe1936-64f9-42de-b2c4-0ddf00529720"}]};

for (const v of clob.Data) {
  const filename = "myfile" + v.Country + '.txt';
  fs.writeFileSync(filename, JSON.stringify(v) + '\n');
}
```

This loops through the `Data` array in the LOB data, and constructs a filename based on the Country name in each array entry.

Answer (score 0):

The result you're getting is a large JSON string. First, you need to parse it into a JavaScript object, from there, you can easily work with the object to get what you need.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const dbConfig = require('./db.js');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var jsonstring;
  oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig, function (err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;
    oracledb.fetchAsString = [oracledb.CLOB];
    connection.execute(
      'select topic from table',
      {},
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) { console.error(err.message); return; }
        if (result.rows.length === 0)
          console.error("No results");

        else {
          var clob = result.rows[0][0];
          console.log(clob);

          const obj = JSON.parse('clob', clob);

          const file1 = obj.data[0];
          console.log('file1', file1);

          const file2 = obj.data[1];
          console.log('file2', file2);
        }
      });
  }
  );
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

I've just shown you how to get the file contents you're after. As you can see, the data property (once the JSON content is parsed) is an array. You can access the elements using hardcoded indexes as I've done or you can use a loop as Chris did.

If you need to write the contents to an actual file on the Node.js server, then Chris' answer should help.